# Excel VBA Not Saving in Current Directory

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, batch-processing

Here is my code below for Excel VBA to batch save Excel files in a directory as PDF. It uses the msoFileDialogFolderPicker to get the user's input.

Everything works except it doesn't save in the current directory with the original files, but it saves in the folder above.

Please let me know what I need to add or change so that it saves in the same folder.

Thanks.

```
Sub BatchProcessing_ExceltoPDF()

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Select Folder Location"
    .ButtonName = "Select"
    .Show
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    cmdSelectInput = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems     (1) & "\"
End With

MyPath = cmdSelectInput
MyTemplate = "*.xls*"  ' Set the template.
MyName = Dir(MyPath & MyTemplate)    'Retrieve the first file
Do While MyName <> ""
    Workbooks.Open MyPath & MyName
    PDFSaveAs
    Workbooks(MyName).Close (True)  'close
    MyName = Dir                    'Get next file
Loop

MsgBox "Finished Excel Batch Processing"

End Sub

Sub PDFSaveAs()
'
' Save Active Excel Sheet to PDF
'
'
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    MyPath & MyName, Quality:= _
    xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the sub PDFSaveAs "MyPath" does not exist as a variable.

As a result all that is passed in is an empty string. It therefore by default saves the file as its existing name but as .pdf in the active directory.

You need to pass in the variables MyPath and MyName to the sub, or else declare them as module level variables.

E.g.:
Option 1:
`Sub PDFSaveAs(MyPath As String, MyName As String)`

called as `PDFSaveAs MyPath, MyName`

or Option2: declare MyPath and MyName at the top of the module as `Private MyPath As String` etc. They will be in scope for PDFSAveAs.

**Always use `Option Explicit` at the top of the module. This will ensure issues over phantom variables like this do not arise.**

Comment: Thank you. I just used Option Explicit then declared all variables.

Comment: @user3565557 you're welcome. I have spent hours trying to debug my own code only to realise the error was something like a silly spelling mistake. I swore to thereafter spend the few extra seconds it takes to always declare my variables. I learnt the lesson the hard way and I am glad to be able to help ;)